# Sharing files with NFS and Unix Permissions

Tags: permissions, nfs

I'm kind of new to using NFS in the context of Linux permissions, so I'm a little lost on how I can make this work.

Here's my setup:

- `alpha` writes files as `root` to the mounted NFS share.
- `beta` serves NFS and reads files from the shared directory, as well as serves the files out over HTTP. The HTTP server runs as user `blaster` with group `server`.

The dilemma I'm facing is that files are written as `root` on `alpha` and can't read or written by user `blaster` of group `server` on `beta`.

The question is: how can I fix this? Do I have to create user `blaster` and group `server` on `alpha` and write files using this user and group in order to allow things to be shared with `beta`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing files as root to an NFS share (by an NFS client) is a really bad idea.  So bad, that the default is to not permit this.

If you want the same privileges on beta as on alpha, then you need to create users with the same User ID on both machines and groups with the same Group ID on both machines.  The actual names are irrelevant, though it is really handy that they are the same.